# set x axis as date for highcharts plot using python flask framework

Tags: python, highcharts, flask

I am using python flask framework to generate dashboard like webpages. I use highcharts as the charting tool. In the test3.html template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block head %}
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.hcharts.cn/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>  
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.hcharts.cn/highcharts/4.0.1/highcharts.js"></script>  

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Average Monthly Temperature and Rainfall in Tokyo'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        xAxis: [{
            categories: '{{chart_x}}',
            crosshair: true
        }],
        yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
            labels: {
                format: '{value}°C',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                }
            }
        }, { // Secondary yAxis
            title: {
                text: 'Rainfall',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                }
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{value} mm',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                }
            },
            opposite: true
        }],
        tooltip: {
            shared: true
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'left',
            x: 120,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 100,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Rainfall',
            type: 'column',
            yAxis: 1,
            data: {{chart_y1}},
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' mm'
            }

        }, {
            name: 'Temperature',
            type: 'spline',
            data: {{chart_y2}},
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '°C'
            }
        }]
    });
});
</script>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<h2>first chart</h2>
<div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>



{% endblock %}
```

and in the view.py:

```
@app.route('/test3')
def test3():
    return render_template("test3.html",
                           title='test3',
                           chart_x=['2014-04-11','2014-04-14','2014-04-15','2014-04-16','2014-04-17','2014-04-18','2014-04-21','2014-04-22','2014-04-23','2014-04-24','2014-04-25','2014-04-28'],
                           chart_y1=[49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
                           chart_y2=[7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
                           )
```

The plot I get is like:

[image]

As you could see, the x axis is not labeled as date, and I am not sure how to set it properly. Anyone could help?

Answer (score 1):

please try with below and it will work without any issue.

```
xAxis: [{ categories: [ {% for item in chart_x %} "{{ item }}", {% endfor %} ], crosshair: true }]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have:

```
    xAxis: [{
        categories: '{{chart_x}}',
        crosshair: true
    }],
```

While should be:

```
    xAxis: [{
        categories: {{chart_x}},
        crosshair: true
    }],
```

Comment: I tried, and it doesn't work. No chart is showed in this case.

Comment: Ok, then what kind of error do you have in console? Does it work when you replace `chart_x` with `chart_y1` ? Do you have then proper numbers?

Answer (score 0):

xAxis: [{
        categories: '{{chart_x}}',
        crosshair: true
    }],
In the above xAxis, you are trying to getting the array of chart_x but you are closing it in string. So instead of in string form, just write only in syntax of {{chart_x}}, then it will work. I have tried it and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

y-Axis works just fine but when we try to use

```
xAxis: [{
        categories: {{chart_x}},
        crosshair: true
    }],
```

the graph disappears. Whereas,

```
xAxis: [{
        categories: '{{chart_x}}',
        crosshair: true
    }],
```

gives some garbage values initially

Something that worked for me is ..

```
xAxis: [{
        categories: [
        '{{chart_x[0}}',
        '{{chart_x[1}}',
        '{{chart_x[2}}',
             ...
        '{{chart_x[11}}',
],
        crosshair: true
    }],
```

I don't know why but this is what I figured out!